# Incremental padding using CSS?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to have incremental padding using CSS? E.g. having the amount of padding increment by X pixels in relation to the viewport when the latter is between x and Y dimensions?

Using @media only works for the first breakpoint, but I would want the padding to change incrementally.

Comment: Why does it only work for the first breakpoint? You can continue setting media queries as needed. [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7vsyv33c/)

Comment: Thank you. I would need the padding to vary by one pixel for every pixel the viewport is reduced between 540px and 500px, so that would require 40 @media rules. I realize this would be better achieved using margins, but was wondering if such a thing would be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `vw` or `vh` units for the padding - those are relative to the viewport.

For example

```
div {
  padding: 2.5vw;
}
```

See http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QEdgeX

(and you can also use `calc` using a pixel value in combination with `vw`)